# I am trying to retrieve data from a particular JSON object situated in an array, but i cannot access the individual items within the "value" object

Tags: java, arrays, json, object

```
"items": [
    {
      "day": 1,
      "mealPlanId": 0,
      "slot": 1,
      "position": 0,
      "type": "RECIPE",
      "value": "{\"id\":913380,\"imageType\":\"jpg\",\"title\":\"Baked Cherry French Toast Casserole\"}"
    },
```

I can retrieve "value" in the form of

```
{"id":657306,"imageType":"jpg","title":"Pumpkin French Toast"}
```

But how can i individually separate them for example, title would = "Baked Cherry French Toast Casserole"
I am using the org.json library Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can just cast your value string in json object with org.json library.
Then access to all the field via this json object.

To  transform your value string in JSON object with org.json

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject("yourValue");
```

look https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json for more documentation